# How can I replace a gadget that I accidentally removed from my gadgets folder?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

I accidentally uninstalled a third party gadget from the gadgets folder on my windows 7 machine.  When I tried to replace the same folder in the path *C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets*, the gadget does not appear in the gadget gallery.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you keep a copy of the gadget after you uninstalled it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find the *.gadget file, it should be "executable" try double clicking on it.. If not, find it on the web and reinstall it..

Answer (score 1):

If you have the installation file, try doubble clicking to install.

You need to install the gadget for it to run on Windows.  See [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/f/install-gadget-windows.htm) article for some additional help.